# What can be said about the convergence of $a_n$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

If $a_n = n!e^n/n^n$, then is $a_n$ a converging sequence or diverging?

Comment: Use Stirling's approximation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation

Comment: Yes, this works well. Thank you. But, is there some other way to proceed?